# Does optimization kill abstraction and vice versa?

Tags: optimization, abstraction

I always find that to write optimized code, I have to understand the inner-workings of the system (in some cases the operating system), and thus my code will be written with certain knowledge that unveils the abstractions of the OS (whether intentionally or unintentionally).

Is this an inherent trait of this interaction? In other words, is abstraction vs optimization a zero-sum game?